# Where is Mysql-server port in openbsd?

Tags: port, openbsd

What's wrong with mysql-server port?? I can't find it anywhere /usr/ports/database/mysql is *mysql-client* only =(

**Please**, don't say something like "you shouldn't use ports", only in that case if ports will be wiped out in openbsd. (lol, I hope this will never happen)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually it's both, the server part is probably a flavour, see: http://openbsd.org/faq/faq15.html#PortsFlavors

Unless you have good reason to compile from source you should check out packages, they're designed to be easy to use and maintain, especially when upgrading to newer versions (see [pkg_add(1)](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=pkg_add&sektion=1&manpath=OpenBSD+4.8))

Comment: $ make show=FLAVORS <-- empty result. pkg_add in this case won't help because tons of dependencies is NEWER in port tree.. and pkg_add requires older mysql-client and some other libs.. and btw this server is so old that it's just a-must to recompile with -Os

Comment: oh ok I undertand now.. "make install-all" was the answer! I never had situtation where I need subpackages in ports X_X. Anyway thnx for the link!

Answer (score 2):

```
cd  /usr/ports/database/mysql/
env SUBPACKAGE="-server" make install
```